# Run a docker container with gocd CI/CD

Tags: docker, go-cd

I have build a CI/CD with gitlab and docker. In my gitlab-ci.yml i just write commands to build and launch container to run test and that's it.

Now i m looking for a way to do the same thing with a GOCD ci/cd server. But the official documentation from gocd directly come to kubernetees or Docker in Docker or Docker outside Docker. I don't need this.

I have one GOCD-server and two GOCD-agents.

I want to build and run ONE container and perhaps deploy it. I m not able to find a simple tutorial to make a pipeline with three stages on GOCD:

1. build the image;
2. run container and test it;
3. deploy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, i was able to get it working by myself, here are the following steps :

### Pre-requisites:

- docker-ce and docker-compose must be installed on each agents
- go user must be on group docker
- /var/run/docker.sock must be on mode 666
- each agent must have an access to your gitlab/github/repository hub and the fingerprint host must be added before first connection

add manually the fingerprint host on each gocd-agent, you must be connected as go user (or don't forget to set the right owner to known_hosts file):

```
  ssh-keyscan -H your.repository.com >> /var/go/.ssh/known_hosts
```

### Then on gocd-server ui:

1. create pipeline
2. create a stage
3. create a job
4. create one or more tasks

   --> add a new task -> choose "more" and you will have the possibility to add a custom command

at this point, you can add in the cell "commands"

```
 /usr/bin/docker
```

or (depends of your use-case)

```
 /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

and in the arguments list, one argument by line

```
 build
 .
 -f
 dockerfile
 -t
 yourrepository/tagOfYourImage
```

After that, don't forget, to clean before and after each run, your containers and created images.
You can also use "/bin/bash" in cell "commands" and then two arguments

```
 -c
 "/usr/bin/docker rmi $(/usr/bin/docker image ls|/usr/bin/grep server_php|/usr/bin/awk '{ print $3 }'|/usr/bin/tr '\r' ' ') --force||true"
```

### Tips:

If you want all your jobs to success on each agent, don't forget to choose the option "Run on all agents" in the tab "Job settings".

### Update:

If you restart docker service or one of your agent, it will remove the 666 permissons on /var/run/docker.sock, adding the user go to the group docker didn't help me. I have to set 666 permissions to this file again.